# Flask post request changes url and refreshes page, when not meant too

Tags: python, html, flask, post, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to have a dropdown button within a spreadsheet in html. When you click the dropdown, there are 3 options under status: accepted, tentative and declined. I tried to set up a post request, so when the user clicks one of the 3 options (buttons), it changes the status in the backend. As there are many many pieces of data, I wanted to use a POST request opposed to a GET request as it would be more efficient since there's 100s of rows that would have this dropdown.

My backend flask is very simple for now, just to test if I can actually get the POST request data, it looks like this:

```
@manage_blueprint.route("/manage/<event_id>", methods=['POST'])
def change_status(event_id: str):
    print('hello world')
    status = request.form.get('status')

    print('status:', status, event_id)
```

and my HTML is as follows:

```
<li>
      <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('manage_bp.change_status', event_id=event.event_id) }}" class="inline">
          <input type="hidden" name="status" value="ACCEPTED">
          <button type="submit" class="{long tailwind class}">Accepted</button>
      </form>
  </li>
```

Do note that the <li> is part of the dropdown, there are 3 of these per drop down (with different values ofc).

When I hit the button you would expect it to not refresh the page and do the process in the backend however, when I click the button it reloads the page and changes the URL to the following:

`http://localhost:5000/manage/0aa693ed-c019-11ee-9d41-dc46285d6447?status=TENTATIVE`

I'm stumped as to how/why its changing the url and not even going into the function and printing hello world. This likely implies it's running a GET request which should not be the case since the function uses a POST request. Just for reference here is another function which uses a GET, but I am in no way calling it:

```
@manage_blueprint.route("/manage/<event_id>", methods=[ 'GET' ])
def manage_event(event_id):
    print(event_id)
    # Query the event from database by id
    event = get_event_by_id(event_id, repo.repo_instance)

    get_users = get_all_users( repo.repo_instance)

    return render_template(
        'manage/manage.html',
        event_id = event_id,
        event = event,
        users = get_users
    )
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If it's got `?status=TENTATIVE` in the URL then it's being sent as a GET method which is why your POST method code isn't being called.

Comment: yep, i figuerd its sending a GET request. I am stumped as to why it would be sending a GET request, even though the function it calls when I click the button uses a POST method.